# Alarms did run at exact time

Tags: android

- I set 2 alarms for 8 AM next day using code below
- Phone (Samsung Galaxy 6) was asleep at 8AM
- Alarms did not run at 8AM
- At 8:50 AM, I pressed the home button
- Now, both the alarms ran and notifications appear on home screen.

I wanted notifications to appear at 8 am with the sound. What is it I am missing for alarms to run at 8AM?

```
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyAlarmReceiver.ALARM_ID, alarmID);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyAlarmReceiver.ALARM_TITLE, notifTitle);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyAlarmReceiver.ALARM_SUBTITLE, subTitle);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyAlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_TAG, notificationTag);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyAlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, notifId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of Android in use on that tablet is most likely Marshmallow or newer (API 23).  In order for your alarm to trigger, you'll have to exclude it from Doze (idle mode) optimizations by calling `alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.